# Matlab display animated gif in gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, gif

I am trying to display a GIF image in my GUI, and it doesn't work. It displays me a fake image (not a GIF, and with different colors).

I know there is an "Animated GIF" in File Exchange but I prefer something else :/
I tried the next code, but it doesn't work:

```
function [] = GUI_400()

     hFig = figure('Name','Simulation Plot Window','Menubar','none', 'Resize','off', 'WindowStyle','modal', 'Position',[300 300 1150 600]);
     movegui(hFig, 'center');

     hAxes = axes('Parent',hFig,'Units','pixels','Position',[362 242 424 359]);  %#   so the position is easy to define
     image(imread('loading.gif', 'gif'),'Parent',hAxes);  %# Plot the image
     set(hAxes,'Visible','off', 'handlevisibility', 'off');          %# Turn the axes visibility off

end
```

this is my gif image:
http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg822/scaled.php?server=822&filename=loadingoz.gif&res=landing

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of a GIF player:

```
function gifPlayerGUI(fname)
    %# read all GIF frames
    info = imfinfo(fname, 'gif');
    delay = ( info(1).DelayTime ) / 100;
    [img,map] = imread(fname, 'gif', 'frames','all');
    [imgH,imgW,~,numFrames] = size(img);

    %# prepare GUI, and show first frame
    hFig = figure('Menubar','none', 'Resize','off', ...
        'Units','pixels', 'Position',[300 300 imgW imgH]);
    movegui(hFig,'center')
    hAx = axes('Parent',hFig, ...
        'Units','pixels', 'Position',[1 1 imgW imgH]);
    hImg = imshow(img(:,:,:,1), map, 'Parent',hAx);
    pause(delay)

    %# loop over frames continuously
    counter = 1;
    while ishandle(hImg)
        %# increment counter circularly
        counter = rem(counter, numFrames) + 1;

        %# update frame
        set(hImg, 'CData',img(:,:,:,counter))

        %# pause for the specified delay
        pause(delay)
    end
end
```

---

#### EDIT

As I mentioned in the comments, the sample GIF image you posted is rather strange. Here are the changes to make it work. Inside the while loop, add the following immediately after the `set(hImg,'CData',..)` line:

```
%# update colormap
n = max(max( img(:,:,:,counter) ));
colormap( info(counter).ColorTable(1:n,:) )
```

Comment: I tried to check this code on other image, but it doesn't work :/ the first frame is good, but the next three are not, the five frame is good and the 6-8 frames are not, etc.. (the bad frames got black, although it white). I put my gif image in my topic. thank you.

Comment: @AlonShmiel: could you upload problematic file somewhere so I can test it? could be a **transparency** thing..

Comment: @AlonShmiel: At first I suspected your sample image was somehow corrupted, but now I think I know what the problem is; each frame (indexed image) in your GIF uses a different colormap. Apparently IMREAD will only return the colormap of the first frame. Thankfully we can get the correct cmap for each frame from IMFINFO `info(idx).ColorTable`. Even with that, the cmap needed to be cropped at the maximum index present in the corresponding image. I'll edited my answer to show you the changes you need to make to get it to work with your image...

Comment: now it works! thank you from my deep of my heart. (In the future, I will try to create a good gif, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend displaying your gif like this. This way, you don't have a nasty while loop blocking callbacks and other code execution.

```
jLabel = javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.JLabel',javaObjectEDT('javax.swing.ImageIcon',which([fname '.gif'])));
[hJ,hC] = javacomponent(jLabel,getpixelposition(hFig).*[0 0 1 1],hFig);
set(hC,'units','normalized','position',[0 0 1 1])
```